# Upgrade to MVC5 exception; 'PagedList.Mvc.PagedListRenderOptions' does not contain a definition for 'DefaultPlusFirstAndLast'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I am upgrading my application from MVC4 to MVC5.
as part of that process I had to upgrade PagedList.Mvc and PagedList via Nuget in order to be compatible.
What I am finding is that the following line

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("FullList", new { page }),
            PagedListRenderOptions.DefaultPlusFirstAndLast)
```

No longer compiles during runtime, I get a "Server Error in '/' Application." and more detail as shown in the title above.

Yet elsewhere in the same View the following line dispalys as expected;

```
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("FullList", new { page }),
            PagedListRenderOptions.MinimalWithPageCountText)
```

The difference is with the PagedListRenderOptions where DefaultPlusFirstAndLast is not recognised.
I am surprised about this as when I look in the object browser, I see that DefaultPlusFirstAndLast is one of the properties that should be available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason intellisense was not working and not giving me any clues as to what the problem is.
Today it was working and I found I had to change DefaultPlusFirstAndLast to ClassicPlusFirstAndLast.

Comment: Amazing what a goog nights sleep does .. even for visual studio :)

Comment: I think it must have got exhausted by the upgrade and decided to take it easy!

Comment: Haha, I don't doubt it!